# Return Mongo document using Mongoose where subdocument does NOT exist?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Help!  I'm losing my mind.  I need to simply return a **Mongo** `document`, using `Mongoose`, `IF` a sub document does not exist.

My schemas:

```
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email: {type: String, unique: true, lowercase: true},
    password: {type: String, select: false},
    displayName: String,
    picture: String,
    facebook: String,
    deactivation: deactiveSchema
});

var deactiveSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    when : { type: Date, default: Date.now, required: true },
    who  : { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true, ref: 'User' }
});
```

My goal is to lookup a user by their `facebook` ID if they have not been deactivated.

If they **have** been deactivated, then a `deactivation` subdocument will exist.  Of course, to save space, if they are active then a `deactivation` will **not** exist.

On a side note, I'm also worried about how to properly construct the index on this logic.

I'd post snippets but every attempt has been wrong.  =(

Comment: What about returning that user document and then checking `if (user.deactivation)`? The use-case for the data will point you in the correct direction.

Comment: Theoretically, if I am querying only on the FB ID, and then checking for the doc AFTER it is returned, I could have multiple docs returned.  Coming from a RDBMS world, I assumed the correct / most graceful way of doing this was to somehow use an index to find the ONE user who matched the condition.  However, now that I think of it, is it even possible to include subdocument info in an index?  Hmm...  man, noobs are a pain sometimes.  :P

Comment: Could you not accomplish the same task by simply using an audit field?  For example, having a `dateDeactivated` field would allow you to index the two fields without having to muck around with subdocuments.

Comment: I too recently chose MongoDB for a project. Mongoose provides an amazingly simple interface for Node.js. I have found it also requires the developer to shift most of the DB logic to the Application Layer. In your case, I think either return everything but password OR only return facbook and deactivation and if (!deactivation) issue another query for the doc. It isn't elegant but queries are much faster in NoSQL land. edited thanks to @G.Deward

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something; if you're querying by FB Id, that field should be restricted to be unique. If it's unique, you'll be using `findOne()` instead of `find()`. Then you will able to just check it in memory when you get a single document back.

Comment: @cdbajorin The goal is to not destroy any data.  So, the FB id might exist on multiple User documents.  It might also not exist at all.  The goal is to be able to retire (or deactivate) a User by moving their social media IDs to a new user document.  I'm also using Satellizer and I'd like to make as few modifications as possible at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$exists` operator:

```
 userSchema.find({deactivation:{$exists:false}}).exec(function(err,document){


  });
```

or `$ne`:

```
 userSchema.find({deactivation:{$ne:null}}).exec(function(err,document){


  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are retiring data and not deleting, I'd go with one of two approaches:

**Flag for retired** *(Recommended)*

add to your schema:

```
retired: {
    type: Boolean,
    required: true
}
```

and add an index for this query:

```
userSchema.index({facebook: 1, retired: 1})
```

and query:

```
User.find({facebook: facebookId, retired: false}, callback)
```

**Query for existence**

```
User.find().exists("deactivation", false).exec(callback)
```

The latter will be slower, but if you really don't want to change anything, it will work. I'd recommend taking some time to read through the [indexing](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/indexes-introduction/) section of the mongo docs.

Answer (score 0):

Mongoose has many options for defining queries with conditions and a couple of styles for writing queries:

#### Condition object

```
var id = "somefacebookid";

var condition = {
  facebook : id, 
  deactivation: { $exists : true}
};

user.findOne(condition, function (e, doc) {
     // if not e, do something with doc
})
```

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html

#### Query builder

Alternatively, you may want to use the query builder syntax if you are looking for something closer to SQL. e.g.:

```
var id = "somefacebookid"; 
users
    .find({ facebook : id }).
    .where('deactivation').exists(false)
    .limit(1)
    .exec(callback);
```

Comment: Would this not require that `deactivation` be set to `null` specifically on the doc?  From what I understand, if the `deactivation` subdocument did not exist at all, this would fail because you're specifically checking for a `null`.  Correct?

Comment: Yes, that's a good point. I was mainly trying to show the 2 ways in which you can perform "sql-like" queries using mongoose. i.e. either by using the condition object or by chaining sql-like commands.  But you are right, I'll update for ```undefined```